# pandas.read_csv in Spark environment (IBM Bluemix)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I'm using `IPython` in a `Spark/Bluemix` environment

I have a csv uploaded to the the object store and I can read it ok using `sc.textfile` but I get `file does not exist` when I use `pandas pd.read_csv`

1. `data = sc.textFile("swift://notebooks.books/rtenews.csv")`
2. `import pandas as pd`
   `data = pd.read_csv('swift://notebooks.books/rtenews.csv')`

`IOError   File swift://notebooks.books/rtenews.csv does not exist`

Why is this?
How can I read a csv file to a `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: Pandas reader supports only local filesystems. Why do you need this?

Comment: It relates to a big data analytics course project and demonstrating the use of Spark/Bluemix and map/reduce is a requirement.  Even though the file starts out on a local file system - I have to process it in Spark/Ipython.

Comment: Just skip Pandas and load data directly to Spark: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28782940/1560062

Comment: But then I miss out on all the pre canned data analysis capabilities of pandas dataframes

Comment: Spark and Pandas are two completely different worlds. If your requirement is Spark and distributed processing then Pandas won't work. Running Pandas in the same interpreter doesn't make it distributed.

Comment: I managed to make some progress with .toDF() on the file loaded with sc.textfile.  I can  do some distributed processing on this and then convert to a Spark dataframe and then toPandas() which has me back in familiar territory. I take your point about the two different purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have uploaded the CSV file to your Bluemix Object Storage, 
you can read the CSV file using Spark directly:

```
data = sc.textFile("swift://notebooks.books/rtenews.csv")
```

This is possible, because configurations have been done to enable this feature.

If you try to read the CSV file with the following code using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('swift://notebooks.books/rtenews.csv')
```

This will not work, because `pandas` do not support direct access of Bluemix Object Storage. Have a look at the API documentation of `pandas.read_csv()`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
It supports a few valid URL schemes, only.

However, it is possible to read a CSV file on you Bluemix Object Storage as `StringIO` object into `pandas.DataFrame`.

You can find the instructions in "Precipitation Analysis" sample notebook:

- Create new notebook from Samples: New Notebook -> Samples Tab -> Precipitation Analysis
- HTML export: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/data/notebooks/samples/Precipitation%20Analysis
- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1oNZwG3tCk

Use this approach not for large CSV files!