# Python - Split a row into columns - csv data

Tags: python, regex, csv, pyspark, rdd

Am trying to read data from csv file, split each row into respective columns.

But my regex is failing when a particular column has **commas with in itself**.

eg: a,b,c,"d,e, g,",f

I want result like:

```
a    b    c    "d,e, g,"    f
```

which is 5 columns.

Here is the regex am using to split the string by comma

> ,(?=(?:"[^"]*?(?:[^"]*)*))|,(?=[^"]+(?:,)|,+|$)

but it fails for few strings while it works for others.

All am looking for is, when I read data from csv using pyspark into dataframe/rdd, I want to load/preserve all the columns without any mistakes

Thank You

Comment: Why bother if there are multiple options available out of the box? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34528938/1560062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much easier with the help of the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module:

```
import regex as re

string = 'a,b,c,"d,e, g,",f'
rx = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,')

parts = rx.split(string)
print(parts)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', '"d,e, g,"', 'f']
```

It supports the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism, which ignores everything betweem double quotes in this example.

---

If you have escaped double quotes, you could use:

```
import regex as re

string = '''a,b,c,"d,e, g,",f, this, one, with "escaped \"double",quotes:""'''
rx = re.compile(r'".*?(?<!\\)"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,')
parts = rx.split(string)
print(parts)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', '"d,e, g,"', 'f', ' this', ' one', ' with "escaped "double",quotes:""']
```

See a demo for the latter on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/iN8rU3/1).

---

For nearly 50 points, I feel to provide the `csv` methods as well:

```
import csv
string = '''a,b,c,"d,e, g,",f, this, one, with "escaped \"double",quotes:""'''

# just make up an iterable, normally a file would go here
for row in csv.reader([string]):
    print(row)
    # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd,e, g,', 'f', ' this', ' one', ' with "escaped "double"', 'quotes:""']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `\,(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)`.

Used [this answer which explains how to match everything that is not in quotes ignoring escaped quotes](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes#6464500) and http://regexr.com/ to test.

Note that - as other answers to your question state - there are better ways to parse CSV than use a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can't easily parse CSV files with regex.

My go-to toolkit for handling CSV from the Unix command line is `csvkit`, which you can get from https://csvkit.readthedocs.io . It has a Python library as well.

The Python docs for the standard csv library are here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

There is an extensive discussion of parsing CSV here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166454/can-the-csv-format-be-defined-by-a-regex

This is a well-trodden path, and the libraries are good enough that you shouldn't roll your own code.