# How to elegantly create a pyspark Dataframe from a csv file and convert it to a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm having a CSV file which I want to read into an RDD or DataFrame. This is working so far, but if I collect the data and convert it into a pandas DataFrame for plotting the table is "malformed".

Here is how I read the CSV file:

```
NUMERIC_DATA_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "train_numeric.csv")
numeric_rdd = sc.textFile(NUMERIC_DATA_FILE)
numeric_rdd = numeric_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x, delimiter=","))
numeric_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(numeric_rdd)
numeric_df.registerTempTable("numeric")
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to correctly set the first row of the CSV data to columns and the first column as index?

---

This problem goes further as I try to select data from the `DataFrame`:

```
numeric_df.select("SELECT Id FROM numeric")
```

which gives me:

```
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'SELECT Id FROM numeric' given input columns _799, _640, _963, _70, _364, _143, _167, 
_156, _553, _835, _780, _235, ...
```

Comment: Try to read your CSV file [properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34528938/5741205). Alternatively you can read your CSV file directly to Pandas DF, using `pd.read_csv(...)` if it fits in your RAM

Comment: This looks like data from the **Bosch Production Line Performance**  (https://www.kaggle.com/c/bosch-production-line-performance/data) kaggle competition. You need lots of RAM for the data to fit in...

Comment: @ShivamGaur 1,8TB should do it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setting a schema for your PySpark DataFrame

Your PySpark DataFrame does not have a schema assigned to it. You should replace your code with the snippet below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
NUMERIC_DATA_FILE = sc.textFile(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "train_numeric.csv"))

# Extract the header line
header = NUMERIC_DATA_FILE.first()

# Assuming that all the columns are numeric, let's create a new StructField for each column
fields = [StructField(field_name, FloatType(), True) for field_name in header]
```

Now, we can construct our schema,

```
schema = StructType(fields)

# We have the remove the header from the textfile rdd

# Extracting the header (first line) from the RDD
dataHeader = NUMERIC_DATA_FILE.filter(lambda x: "Id" in x)

# Extract the data without headers. We can make use of the `subtract` function
dataNoHeader = NUMERIC_DATA_FILE.subtract(dataHeader)

numeric_temp_rdd = dataNoHeader.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x, delimiter=","))
```

The Schema is passed in as a parameter into the `createDataFrame()` function

```
numeric_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(numeric_temp_rdd,schema)
numeric_df.registerTempTable("numeric")
```

Now, if you wish to convert this DataFrame to a Pandas dataframe, use the `toPandas()` function:

```
pandas_df = numeric_df.limit(5).toPandas()
```

### The following statement will work as well:

```
numeric_df.select("Id")
```

### If you want to use pure SQL, you need to use SQLContext to query your table

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext  =  SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql('SELECT Id from numeric')
```

Comment: Hm, I can't make it run. Still getting the error for the `select()` call and for `numeric_df.take(5)` it's throwing a `TypeError` somewhere "*unhashable type: 'list'*" - I don't know where this is happening.

Comment: `numeric_df.select("Id")` should work. Corrected the syntax

Comment: ^ This style of is similar to SQLAlchemy. if you wish to use pure SQL Statements, then you need to use the sql context