# how to load large csv with many fields to Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Happy New Year!!!

I know this type of similar question has been asked/answered before, however, mine is different:

I have large size csv with 100+ fields and 100MB+, I want to load it to Spark (1.6) for analysis, the csv's header looks like the attached [sample](http://www.rocksled.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/flight201601_sample.csv) (only one line of the data)

Thank you very much.

UPDATE 1(2016.12.31.1:26pm EST):

I use the following approach and was able to load data (sample data with limited columns), however, I need to auto assign the header (from the csv) as the field's name in the DataFrame, BUT, the DataFrame looks like:

[image]
Can anyone tell me how to do it? Note, any manual manner is what I want to avoid.

```
>>> import csv
>>> rdd = sc.textFile('file:///root/Downloads/data/flight201601short.csv') 
>>> rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x))
>>> rdd.take(5) 
>>> df = rdd.toDF() 
>>> df.show(5)
```

Comment: What problem do you experience loading this dataset using standard methods? (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34528938/7098262)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the 100+ fields, to explicitly add all the fields is a tedious job and I believe there should be a mature way to handle it

Comment: Take a look at exact answer I referenced above - if you use spark-csv package to read file there is `header` options that will solve your problem easily.

Comment: Thanks. `pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0` resolve the issue in spark 1.6

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comments you can use spark.read.csv for spark 2.0.0+ (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

```
df = spark.read.csv('your_file.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

Setting *header* to *True* will parse the header to column names of the dataframe. Setting *inferSchema* to *True* will get the table schema (but will slow down reading).

See also here:
[Load CSV file with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782940/load-csv-file-with-spark)

Comment: Thanks, I am on Spark 1.6, Mariusz's answer above resolves the issue.