# How to show my existing column name instead '_c0', '_c1', '_c2', '_c3', '_c4' in first row?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

Data frame showing _c0,_c1 instead my original column names in first row.
    i want to show My column name which is on first row of my CSV.

```
    dff = 
    spark.read.csv("abfss://dir@acname.dfs.core.windows.net/
    diabetes.csv")
    dff:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
    _c0:string
    _c1:string
    _c2:string
    _c3:string
    _c4:string
    _c5:string
    _c6:string
    _c7:string
    _c8:string
```

Comment: Use `header=True`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load CSV file with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782940/load-csv-file-with-spark) (the most upvoted answer, not the accepted one)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very simple solution is to have a header=True while you read the file:

```
dff = spark.read.csv("abfss://dir@acname.dfs.core.windows.net/diabetes.csv", header=True)
```

Comment: If headers are indeed blank I want it to remain blank instead of appending it with _c0 etc., do we have any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Set header as true while loading the CSV file.

```
spark.read.format("csv")
                   .option("delimiter", ",")
                   .option("header", "true")
                   .option("inferSchema", "true")
                   .load("file.csv")
```

Answer (score -1):

I Just Sorted By below code

```
    .select(col("_c0").alias("A"),
             col("_c1").alias("B"),
             col("_c2").alias("C"),
             col("_c3").alias("D"),
             col("_c4").alias("E")

            )
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it this way because then the first row in your dataframe would contain the header

Comment: Yeah you are right i just put "Header=true" that work for me thanks for your help.

Comment: You should delete this answer and accept the duplicate target